# OnPaint is not a member of wxWindows?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm using my own variant of a `wxPanel` which itself makes use of its own paint-method to draw a custom image `m_image`:

```cpp
void wxImagePanel::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent & evt)
{
    wxPaintDC dc(this);

    dc.SetBackground(*wxWHITE_BRUSH);
    dc.Clear();

    dc.DrawBitmap(*m_image,6,4,false);
    wxWindow::OnPaint(evt);
}
```

The final call to `wxWindow::OnPaint(evt)` is there to let wxWidgets draw some GUI-elements on top of that image.

This works and compiles well with Windows, but when trying to build this application with Linux (Ubuntu 22.04LTS), I get an error:

```
error: ‘OnPaint’ is not a member of ‘wxWindow’
  335 |    wxWindow::OnPaint(evt);
      |              ^~~~~~~
```

The same happens when I try `wxPanel::OnPaint(evt)`.

So, how can it happen that this does not compile for Linux only? Can't `OnPaint()` be found in `wxWindow`?

Comment: No, it does not have this method https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html. **I'm using an own variant of a wxPanel** Show it. We can't guess.

Comment: OnPaint is not listed as a public or protected method of wxWindow, so it's surprising that your code compiles on Windows, not the other way around.

Comment: @273K OK, then what is the proper, valid and official method to let the superordinated class do its paint-job?

Comment: If  you need a window to be repainted, use `wxWindow::Refresh()`.

Comment: There is no `OnPaint`. You just need to `Bind` the paint event and to give it action as mentioned call `Refresh`

Comment: @Elmi, in you code are you really explicitly calling `OnPaint` method and not using EVT_PAINT?

Answer (score 0):

You should never call the base class event handler directly and not only because it may not exist but because the event handling logic in wxWidgets is more complex, in general, than that. Instead, you should either process the event (which you will typically do for `wxEVT_PAINT`, it doesn't make much sense to paint the window yourself and then do something else) or not, and in the latter case you need to call [evt.Skip()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_event.html#a98eb20b76106f9a933c2eb3ee119f66c) to let the event handling code know that it should keep processing the event.

Again, for `wxEVT_PAINT` events you almost never want to do this anyhow. But for some other events, e.g. focus ones, you almost always do need to call `Skip()`.